# stripping a pattern from the end of the string

Tags: python

I want to see if a file like test_100.webp exists and then look at the file test.yaml. Therefore, I need to strip the pattern "_100.webp" from the end. I tried to use the code below and it is giving me issues.

```
 for i, image in enumerate(images_in_item):
        if image.endswith("_100.webp"):
            image_strip = image.rstrip(_100.webp)
            snapshot_markup = os.path.join(image_strip + 'yaml')
```

Comment: Try `image_strip = image.replace('_100.webp', '')`

Comment: Basically it was also removing other occurrences of other characters from the string. 200_100.webp will be reduced to 2 if image.rstrip("_100.webp") is used.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
suffix = '_100.webp'
if image.endswith(suffix):
    image_strip = image[:-len(suffix)]
    snapshot_markup = os.path.join(image_strip + 'yaml')
```